# How can I limit the thread behavior to the method that calls them?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this sample class:

```
public class Multithreading extends Thread {
    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        call1();
        call2();
    }

    private static void call2() {

        Multithreading call2obj1 = new Multithreading() {
            public void run() {

            }
        };
        call2obj1.start();

    }

    private static void call1() {

        Multithreading call1obj1 = new Multithreading() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("call1obj1");
                sleep(5000);
            }
        };
        Multithreading call1obj2 = new Multithreading() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("call1obj2");
                sleep(5000);
            }
        };
        call1obj1.start();
        call1obj2.start();

    }
}
```

What I want is for `call2()` to wait until `call1()` is fully complete. i.e., `call1obj2` need not wait until `call1obj1` is done executing, but `call2obj1` should wait until both `call1obj1` and `call1obj2` are done.

Basically the thread behavior of `call1obj1` and `call1obj2` must be limited to `call1()`;

Is that possible?

Comment: what about : call1obj1.join(); and call1obj2.join(); ?

Comment: Take a look at [`Thread#join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29), or use synchronization practices like `wait...notify` or [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Comment: I have tried that. It is making `call1obj2` also wait for `call1obj1`.

@v sambor Edit: I was trying 

 `call1obj1.start();
 call1obj1.join();
 call1obj2.start();
 call1obj2.join();`

but 
 `call1obj1.start();
 call1obj2.start();
 call1obj1.join();
 call1obj2.join();`

works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using CountDownLatch:

```
public class Multithreading extends Thread {
static int i = 0;

private static CountDownLatch LATCH;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    // Initialize the latch with the number of threads to finish
    LATCH = new CountDownLatch(2);

    call1();

    // Main thread will wait until all thread finished
    LATCH.await();

    call2();
}

private static void call2() {

    Multithreading call2obj1 = new Multithreading() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("call2obj1");
        }
    };
    call2obj1.start();

}

private static void call1() {

    Multithreading call1obj1 = new Multithreading() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("call1obj1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                LATCH.countDown();
            }
        }
    };
    Multithreading call1obj2 = new Multithreading() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("call1obj2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                LATCH.countDown();
            }
        }
    };
    call1obj1.start();
    call1obj2.start();

}
```

}

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.